# Android: OnClickListener in ListView Adapter not Working sometimes

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView with several Items that contains Progress Bars. I currently have a Thread setup to update the Progress of each of the Bars as follows:

```
 h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            game.update();
            h.postDelayed(this, 20);
        }
    }, 20);
```

I then update the Progress for Each List Item like so:

```
 progress += timeInc;
 if (progress >= progressMax)
     completeWork();
     updateView();
```

The updateView method does the following:

```
public void updateView() {
    try {
        activity.runOnUiThread(updateView);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (listView != null)
            listView.post(updateView);
    }
}
```

So Basically, I am Calling notifyDataSetChanged several Times every Second. When I dont do this, the progress of the ProgressBar does not move, however I can click on Items normally. But while calling it so many times, sometimes the OnCLickListener on the Items in the list is not triggered. I think it may get interrupted somehow by the call of notifyDataSetChanged.

Here is where I apply my OnClickListener in the Adapter:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (files != null) {
                if (!files.get(position).isClicked()) {
                    // FAILED TO INTERACT:

                }
            }
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(fileAdapter);
    updateView = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fileAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.invalidate();
        }
    };
```

What is the Issue here? And what other way is there to update the progressBars without having to call this method so many times?

Update: I decreased the number of times the method is called, and the clicks are more responsive now. But it still happens sometimes.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a solution. Rather than updating the entire list, I just update the individual Items as follows:

```
public boolean updateProgress(File file) {
    if (listView == null)
        return false;
    int position = files.indexOf(file);
    int first = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int last = listView.getLastVisiblePosition();
    if (position < first || position > last) {
        return false;
    } else {
        View convertView = listView.getChildAt(position - first);
        ProgressBar bar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        if (file.isWorking()) {
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bar.setMax(file.progressMax);
            bar.setProgress(file.progress);
            bar.invalidate();
        } else {
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main reason cause the `onClickListener` not working sometime is your `Main Thread` (`UI Thread`) is very busy. Because of you update UI every second and you have more items so workload is very big --> some time when you `click on Item`, `Main Thread` was busy and can not response.

Comment: Yes. I realized that. Finally figured out a solution. :) Thank you

Comment: Could you please share your solution as an accepted answer ? It will be helpful for some one, including me ^^

Comment: I answered the question :)